# Como hago para el end no agregue un elemento al final de la linea

Tags: python

Ejemplo:

```python
num= int(intput("ingresé un número: ")
for va1 in range(1, num, 2):
    print(va1, end=",")
```

Cuando ejecuto este ejemplo, siempre me deja una `,` al final y eso no es lo que quiero.

Comment: ¿`print` a secas? Hay que leer la documentación...

Answer (score 4):

[`print`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#print) tiene un argumento justo para esto, `sep` ("separator"), basta una sola llamada a `print` y desempaquetar el iterable retornado por `range`:

```
num = int(input("ingresé un número: "))
print(*range(1, num, 2), sep=",")
```

`*iterable` en este contexto desempaqueta el iterable en argumentos posicionales de la función. Es decir, `print(*range(3))` equivale a `print(0, 1, 2)`. Por lo tanto puedes usar esta sintaxis con otros iterables también, como una lista:

```
num = int(input("ingresé un número: "))

results = []
for val in range(1, num, 2):
    res = val ** 2 + 1
    results.append(res)

print(*results, sep=",")
```

o con una expresión generadora (que equivale a lo anterior en cuanto a salida):

```
num = int(input("ingresé un número: "))
print(*(val ** 2 + 1 for val in range(1, num, 2)), sep=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

como indica la [documentacion](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) solo debes dejar en blanco el parametro `end`

```py
print('sin salto de linea', end='')
print('con salto de linea')
```

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo quieres imprimir encadenadamente, pero que no salga el último caracter.

En tu código, por ejemplo, para `num = 6` se obtiene:

Salida: `1,3,5,`

Una forma de evitar ese comportamiento es calculando la cadena previamente y luego imprimirla. En el siguiente caso, el primer `print` muestra la misma cadena que tu ejemplo, pero luego se hace un [slicing](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+slicing+list) para quitar la última coma.

```python
num = 6 # <-- Valor de prueba
res = ''
for va1 in range(1, num, 2):
   res += str(va1) + ','
   
print(res) # 1,3,5,
print(res[:-1]) # 1,3,5
```

Sin embargo eso es mucho código para algo tan trivial. El propio python trae el método [str.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) para hacer exactamente lo que necesitas, donde `str` es la subcadena que separará los elementos del iterable interno, en este caso una lista por [comprensión](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```python
num = 6 # <-- Valor de prueba
print(','.join([str(x) for x in range(1, num, 2)])) # 1,3,5
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi opción es imprimir el separador **antes** que el siguiente elemento. El separador originalmente vale nada, y se reasigna en cada ciclo:

```
separador = " "
for va1 in range(1, num, 2):
    print(separador, va1, end="")
    separador = ","
```

**Demo**

```
Ingrese un número: 10
  1, 3, 5, 7, 9
Process finished with exit code 0
```